# Freshly cloned Tika build fails

Tags: maven, apache-tika

I am trying to install **Apache Tika** on Windows and am running `mvn install` as per the instructions

When I do so I get a failure as shown below:

```
Tests run: 12, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParserTest
testSubclassingMimeTypesRemain(org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...-vcalendar; charset=[ISO-8859-1]> but was:<...-vcalendar; charset=[windows-1252]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParserTest.testSubclassingMimeTypesRemain(TXTParserTest.java:299)
```

How can I resolve this to get Apache Tika running on Windows?

Comment: What instructions are you following that lead you to believe you need to install from source? You really really don't! Apache Tika ships binaries!

Comment: I want to learn as much as possible about Tika and get to the point where, should the need arise, I can extend it.  I can work with a binary distribution as a starting point.

Comment: Almost all of the Tika extension points (and all of the public/common supported extension points) can be done without needing to recompile Apache Tika! See https://tika.apache.org/1.16/parser_guide.html for writing your own parser for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, there is a failure in one of the unit tests... well, you can skip them all and compile in safety using this parameter `-DskipTests=true`.

So the complete command will be: `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`